# custom menu parameter in joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I have a requirement which I just cant seem to work out, I've tried for days!

basically I have created extra field options in my article. But not all fields will be want to be seen on certain pages. So I want to be able to select which fields to show in my menu parameter.

For instance.
I create a profile page with name,age,job,hobbies,experience.

I might want to use this profile twice but each time showing different fields. So I then create a menu item and within that have a list of the fields to select with perhaps a checkbox. The fields selected would then be viewable on the article frontend.

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you already have a custom view that shows these parameters.

Most likely you want to add some parameters to the view's .xml file, you'd be better off creating a dedicated view inside com_content (starting from the one you already created or from article)

Then, you need to modify the view code to take the parameters into account and display the appropriate fields.

From your menu item configuration, once you select the new view, you should now see the configuration parameters available.

If you explain with more details what you've done so far it may be easier to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the help. basically at the moment, All I've created is extra fields which attached themselves to the article (I used the 'fieldsattach' component).